# how to append to multiple lists inside a list

Tags: python, mysql, database, list, sqlalchemy

```
def get_users(self, department_ids, selectable=User, is_alive=True, except_main_department_owner=False):
    """
        Returns all users of given departments
    """
    query_ob = self.session.query(selectable).join(User.departments).filter(
        Department.id.in_(department_ids))

    if except_main_department_owner:
        query_ob = query_ob.filter(
            User.id != DefaultValue.DEFAULT_MAIN_DEPARTMENT_OWNER_ID
        )

    if is_alive:
        query_ob = query_ob.filter(
            User.is_alive
        )

    return query_ob.all()
```

when i call passing an individual id like for example:

```
d_user = [helper.get_users([1], is_alive=True, except_main_department_owner=True)]
```

it returns the values.

but when i want a series of lists:

```
helper = DepartmentHelper(self.session, self.login_user)
d_user = [helper.get_users([id], is_alive=True, except_main_department_owner=True) for id in self.data_departments]
```

it throws me an error.

```
"Failed processing pyformat-parameters; %s" % err)
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: 
(mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) Failed processing pyformat-
parameters; 'MySQLConverter' object has no attribute 
'_department_to_mysql'
```

Comment: Are you trying to append lists to a list? As in list of lists?

Comment: can you also add an example of input and corresponding output

Comment: each_department_lists_of_users = [[],[],[],[],[],....,[]], and i want to add users to it, like, each_department_lists_of_users = [[1,2,3,4],[6,7,8],...,[89,89]]

Comment: Could you be more specific we cannot understand what you want exactly

Comment: so, i have n number of departments, and for each department, i have n number of users. and i have created a list in which there are n number of lists, and each list will contain n number of users

Comment: So you want to know how you will add a list inside a list?

Comment: yes, how will the loop be like

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what your asking, but I think you're asking about concatenating two lists.

```
list1=list2+list3
```

This will concatenate two lists

Answer (score 0):

In your [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44079900/how-to-append-to-multiple-list-inside-a-list) (I think you should stick to *one* question, and work to formulate a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)), you specify that you get your users from this function:

```
def get_users(self, department_ids, selectable=User, is_alive=True, except_main_department_owner=False):    
    """Returns all users of given departments

    """
    query_ob = self.session.query(selectable).join(User.departments).filter(
        Department.id.in_(department_ids))

    return query_ob.all()
```

From your comments, you specify that your departments are numbered 1..n. You could then get a list of lists of users with a list comprehension:

```
n = 9
department_ids = range(1,n+1)
users_per_department = [self.get_users([id]) for id in department_ids]
```

Comment: but i dont want the same repetitive version in every lists. i have different users for each lists

Comment: Can you give an example of original `users_per_department` list and what you want it to be after adding users?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44079900/how-to-append-to-multiple-list-inside-a-list

check this, if it helps

Comment: departments = [1,2,3,4,...,n]
users = [1,2] for department 1
users = [3,4] for department 2
.....
department list = [[],[],[],[],,...,[]]

so i want like, department list = [[1,2],[3,4] ..., []]

Comment: did you get it?

Comment: um, it works if i put an integer value in place of [id], when i try using for loop, gives me an error, sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) Failed processing pyformat-parameters; 'MySQLConverter' object has no attribute '_department_to_mysql' , can you help?

Comment: Try reading the documentation for the MySQL library you're using. If you need more help, post a different question or update this one with details so that it constitutes a SSCCE (link above).

Answer (score 0):

You can reference list items using square brackets (counted from zero):

```
some_list = [[],[],[]]
some_list[1] += [1,2,3]
```

Now `some_list` contains `[[], [1, 2, 3], []]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achive this by the following example

```
department=[]
department.append([1,2,..])
```

so :

```
department=[[1,2,],]
```

Comment: Is this what you want?